# When to use git mv command

Tags: git

I could use the git mv file directory to move the file to a directory. But the same can
be achieved by using the Linux command mv. Is there any difference between these two?
Does it matter if I move a file using the `git mv` or `mv` command?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124683/what-is-the-difference-between-running-git-mv-versus-just-mv

Comment: Have a look at <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124683/what-is-the-difference-between-running-git-mv-versus-just-mv>

Answer (score 0):

git mv automatically stages the moved file, so a simple git commit will suffice after your move or rename is complete.

Reference the article at for more information.
https://initialcommit.com/blog/git-mv